# According to a certain bond code to find the data of all its dates, how should I design the database?

Tags: dolphindb

According to a certain bond code to find the data of all its dates, how should I design the database?
 
The amount of data of a bond is about 2500 per day, how should I design the database reasonably?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is as follows:

```py
n=1000
ID=rand(`A`B`C, n)
dates=2017.08.07..2017.08.11
date=rand(dates, n)
x=take(0..49, n) + 0.1
t=table(ID, date, x)

db1 = database(, VALUE, ID)
db2 = database(, RANGE, date(datetimeAdd(2000.01M,0..40*12,'M')))
db = database("dfs://test1", COMPO, [db1, db2])
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, `pt, `ID`date)
pt.append!(t)
pt=loadTable(db,`pt)
```

The partition rules after data are shown following:
[image]

VALUE will automatically increase the partition. When a new code comes, this code partition will be created automatically. For writing, as long as each thread writes 1 code, concurrent writing will not be a problem.